# How to get more than 100 Tasks

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, podio

We trying to retrieve tasks under the Organization using this https://developers.podio.com/doc/tasks/get-tasks-77949 - Sandbox.
We get 100 tasks only, but we need to bring the entire task. Is there any way we can get more than 100 tasks.
Please Help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the offset and limit parameters?

Comment: please review provided answer and accept it if it helps you, this will also help other people with same question

Answer (score 5):

There is another parameter called 'offset', that should work for getting another 100 tasks.

Here is working example for **Ruby**:

```
  all_tasks = []
  options = {'responsible' => <user id>, 'limit' => 100, 'sort_by' => 'created_on', 'sort_desc' => true}
  while true
    options['offset'] = all_tasks.length
    result = Podio::Task.find_all(options)
    all_tasks += result
    break if result.empty? || result.length < options['limit']
  end
  puts all_tasks.length
```

Output for my execution was `106` :)